# Como Ler arquivo e armazenar cada palavra do arquivo em um vetor em C

Tags: c, array, string

Preciso realizar a leitura de uma arquivo texto (parágrafo) e armazenar cada palavra lida em um vetor, para depois conseguir manipular esse vetor e fazer a contagem de duplicadas.

Esse é o trecho da função que tenho tentado arrumar e está retornando o seguinte erro.

```
tagcloud.c:78:29: warning: assignment to 'char' from 'char *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion] 78 | palavras[i] = palavra;
```

```c
lerArquivo()
{
    char linha[TAM];
    char *palavra = NULL;
    FILE *arquivo;
    char palavras[TAM];
    int i=0;

    arquivo = fopen("arquivo.txt", "r");

    if(arquivo == NULL)
    {
        printf("arquivo.txt - arquivo não encontrado\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(fgets(linha, TAM, arquivo) != NULL)
    {
        if(strchr(linha, '\n') != NULL)
            linha[strlen(linha) - 1] = '\0';

            palavra = strtok(linha, " ");

            while(palavra != NULL)
            {
                palavras[i] = palavra;
                i++;
                palavra = strtok(NULL, " ");
            }
    }


        for(int i = 0; i < TAM; i++){
            printf("%s/n", palavras[i]);
        }
}
```

Comment: Poste um programa completo, compilável.  Se vai usar um vetor apenas se prepare antes e grave no vetor já na ordem, por exemplo usando insertion sort, já que vai ler as palavras uma a uma. E acrescente um contador para quando a palavra já estiver no vetor apenas incrementar. Isso resolve o problema das duplicatas. Se preocupe em definir a palavra: vai diferenciar maiúsculas?

Comment: se você quer dizer que uma palavra seja um conjunto de caracteres separado por um espaço em branco , então seria melhor você usar a função fscanf para ler o arquivo , pois essa fscanf lê uma palavra dessas de cada vez ,

Comment: se você quer dizer que uma palavra seja um conjunto de caracteres separado por um espaço em branco , então seria melhor você usar a função fscanf para ler o arquivo , pois essa fscanf lê uma palavra dessas de cada vez ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A utilização de `fgets` e `strtok` para ler e isolar palavras é uma solução adequada. A utilização de `strtok` permite a utilização de outros caracteres separadores como TAB ou pontuação.

O armazenamento de todo o ficheiro num vetor para posterior processamento, não  me parece uma boa solução porque não introduz avanço na resolução do problema.

O processamento de cada palavra pode ser feito logo após o seu isolamento por parte do `strtok`. Para isso é preciso manter um registro das palavras e do número de vezes que ocorreram.
Para registrar a informação associada a cada palavra pode usar-se uma *struct*:

```
struct palavra {
    char palavra[DIMENSAO_MAXIMA_PALAVRA];
    int contador;
};
```

Para registrar todas as palavras pode usar-se um vetor cujos elementos são `struct palavra`:

```
struct palavra palavras[NUMERO_MAXIMO_PALAVRAS];
```

Atenção à cópia de vetores. A afetação `palavras[i] = palavra;` que aparece no código da pergunta, está errada. Primeiro porque `palavras[i]` representa o tipo char e `palavra` é um ponteiro; segundo, se a intenção é copiar a palavra completa, terá que ser realizada `caracter-a-caracter`, com um ciclo, ou invocando a função de biblioteca `strcpy`.

Esta não é uma solução sofisticada mas é viável.